# Filtrar e contar dados de modelos relacionados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, relacionamento

Empresa `hasMany` SetorEmpresa

SetorEmpresa `belongsTo` Empresa

SetorEmpresa `hasMany` Funcionario

Funcionario `belongsTo` SetorEmpresa

Com esses dados em mãos, como faço para contar quantos **funcionarios com id_status = 1** estão alocados em **setores do tipo = "Administrativo"**? Tentei da maneira abaixo, mas não funcionou e acho que estou longe da maneira certa.

```
{{ $empresa->SetorEmpresa->where('tipo', 'Administrativo')->Funcionario->where('id_status', 1)->count() }}
```

Estou usando Laravel 5.1 e esses dados serão carregados em uma view a partir do objeto Empresa.

Comment: Você precisa ser mais claro, sua pergunta ficou muito confusa. Tente dar mais detalhes, para que possamos te ajudar

Comment: obrigado, mas eu consegui resolver @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, consegui da seguinte forma:

```
{{ $adm = 0 }}

@foreach($empresa->SetorEmpresa->where('tipo', 'Administrativo') as $setor_adm)
     {{ $adm += $setor_adm->Funcionario->where('id_status', 1)->count() }}
@endforeach

{{ $adm }}
```

Assim ele percorre todos os setores administrativos da empresa e conta quantos funcionários ativos tem em cada um deles